# Asigning task to selective users from the list

Tags: workflow, task-list

I need advanced sharepoint help and hoping that someone can help me...

I have 20 teams in my group and for each task I need to select certain teams each time and not all will be asked to review the task for each new task which made this complex.

I created 2 lists already... 
The first list contains names of *team names* and *team leaders*.

Second list is where task is assigned and specific teams are selected.

Also I created a 3rd TASK List so feedback is collected.

However I can not make the workflow work... My workflow is tied to task assignment list but where I am failing is not being able to assign this task to only selected teams...

Most of the help I read says that create a group but for my case based on the task I might need to assign a task to only 3 teams out of 20

Can anybody recommend me a good solution?

Thank you all

Luca

Comment: Luca, can you make SharePoint Permission Groups for 20 of the teams? and then on Task Assignment list, let the person select teams from the SharePoint Groups! What is the workflow doing by the way?